# Исполнение onclick события для нескольких элементов

Tags: javascript, html

Необходимо одним кликом заставить сработать событие onclick на нескольких элементах. 
Основная проблема в том, что использовать средства JS для имитации клика нельзя, это должен быть пользователь.

К примеру, необходимо чтобы сработало сразу четыре алерта с одного клика.

```
<p onclick='alert(1)'>text</p>
<p onclick='alert(2)'>text</p>
<p onclick='alert(3)'>text</p>
<p onclick='alert(4)'>text</p>
```

Возможно элементы должны иметь один класс или быть наложены друг на друга? Как такое реализовать?

Comment: Интересно, и в чем же вы видите разницу между кликами пользователями и кликами из js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно изощриться вот так (использовать всплытие события):

```
<p onclick='alert(1)'>
  text
  <span onclick='alert(2)'>
    text
    <span onclick='alert(3)'>
      text
      <span onclick='alert(4)'>text</span>
    </span>
  </span>
</p>
```

Но в здравом рассудке, так делать не стоит.

Answer (score 1):

Вот как то так, только клинутый елемент будет 2 раза выдовать алерт, так как будет срабатывать первый onclick

```js
let matches = document.body.querySelectorAll('p');
for(i=0; i < matches.length; i++)
{
 matches[i].addEventListener('click', function(el){
 for(j=0;j < matches.length; j++)
 {
   matches[j].click();
 }
 })
}
```

```html
<p onclick='alert(1)'>text</p>
<p onclick='alert(2)'>text</p>
<p onclick='alert(3)'>text</p>
<p onclick='alert(4)'>text</p>
```

Comment: Устроит ли это автора? ))  `Основная проблема в том, что использовать средства JS для имитации клика нельзя, это должен быть пользователь.`

Comment: да полностью согласен с вами

Answer (score 0):

Как же нельзя, если есть метод `elem.click()`. Главное, чтобы при клике не было всплывающих окон(`alert()` не считается).
Ну а сразу по нескольким элементам тоже можно, только напишите класс какой-то. Сам код:

```
var all_elems = document.getElementsByClassName("your_class");
for(var i = 0;  i < all_elems.length; i++){
    all_elems[0].click();
}
```

Comment: _Основная проблема в том, что использовать средства JS для имитации клика нельзя, это должен быть пользователь_